# You have an error in your SQL syntax? Works on its own, but get error when doubled up

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, mysqli

Bit puzzled by this, when i comment out the second query i get no error, the first query runs fine but when the second one (basicly the same query) is added i get you have an error in your sql syntax.
Little bit unsure why, any help is appreciated maybe there is a better way for me to do the query, thanks.

SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 [1064]

SQL

SELECT username FROM forum_users WHERE user_id =

BACKTRACE

```
$challengingClan = $results->get('challengingClan');
$query = "SELECT username FROM forum_users WHERE user_id = $challengingClan";
$user1 = $db->sql_query($query);
$user1 = $db->sql_fetchrow($user1);

$opposingClan = $results->get('opposingClan');
$query = "SELECT username FROM forum_users WHERE user_id = $opposingClan";
$user2 = $db->sql_query($query);
$user2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($user2);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$results->get('opposingClan')` returns a valid value?

Comment: Can you print the query and post it plz

Comment: Please edit your post with the output of `echo $query;`

Comment: @ctrahey You were correct with $results->get('opposingClan') for some reason it was returning no value. Feel abit stupid now, silly little thing like that

Comment: Cool. I've posted it as an answer so we can close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that `$results->get('opposingClan')` is not returning anything. This should be easy to debug :-)

Answer (score -1):

it is because you are telling the variables $results and $query to be two different things change one of them